# Return code 127 when waiting for process id

Tags: shell

I am currently running an Ab Initio command from a ksh script. The process is giving me a return code of 127..

```
air sandbox run ${PSET_FILE_PATH} -SOURCE_DATA_DT ${LAST_DATE_CURR_MON} -AI_LOG_FILE ${LOG_FILE} >> ${LOG_FILE} 2>&1 &
    process_id=${$}
    sleep 60
    ps -e -oruser=UID -opid,ppid,vsz,args=CMD | grep "${USER}" | grep -v grep | grep -v 'ps '  > ${ENV_BASE}/cems/recovery/hltcheck/${USER}_startup_mem.txt
    wait ${process_id}
    RC=${?}
    [[ ${RC} -eq 0 ]] || End ERROR "Pset execution of creating mfs failed"
```

Comment: There are lots of processes here. Which one produces the 127 return code (which, incidentally, is the return code used by the shell to indicate a command could not be found).

Comment: Do you mean `process_id=$!`?

Comment: the wait ${process_id} is returning the error code

Comment: Dear Brian, in many cases braces are not required and you can save typing and improve readibility; you can use for example `$PSET_FILE_PATH` and `RC=$?` (and others) directly.

Answer (score 2):

The script is not doing what I think you want it to do.

1. The return code "127" is because the `wait ${process_id}` command returns it since the process id received as argument is not a background process.
2. The process id to wait for is not correct because the command `process_id=${$}` receives the PID of the current shell script instance. The correct thing would be to use `process_id=$!` which will assign the PID of the last process put in background.

The Retur