# wait command behaves differently on Bash and Ash

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ash

Given the following simple snippet, saved in a file named `test.sh`:

```
sleep 3 && exit 50&
echo "Wait for ${!} for the first time."
wait "${!}"
echo "Exit code is: ${?}"
sleep 1     # this line makes a difference
echo "Wait for ${!} for the second time."
wait "${!}"
echo "Exit code is: ${?}"
```

Running the file using `bash test.sh` gives the following output:

```
Wait for 40781 for the first time.
Exit code is: 50
Wait for 40781 for the second time.
Exit code is: 50
```

While running the file using `sh test.sh` (I tried on both Ubuntu dash and BusyBox ash) gives the following output:

```
Wait for 40773 for the first time.
Exit code is: 50
Wait for 40773 for the second time.
Exit code is: 127
```

In `ash`, all commands put between 2 calls to `wait "${!}"` make the exit code change to 127, with the exception of `echo` command. Also, with the `sleep 1` line removed, running the file using `sh test.sh` gives exit code `50`, but manually copying all lines and pasting to the `sh` terminal gives `127` again.

I really don't understand this behavior, and it causes me quite a lot of headache debugging my code. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/3196753), the `$!` variable represents "The PID of the most recent background command".  In the example above, there is one and only one background command:

```bash
sleep 3 && exit 50& # <-- "&" sends to background
```

The second call to `sleep` is not executed as a background command.

```
sleep 1 # <-- This is missing the "&" to send it to the background
```

The difference in behavior is with the `wait` command, which is a [shell built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3193147/3196753).  Shell built-ins can and will change in behavior between different shell implementations.

- In `bash`, when you ask `wait` to wait for a process that's already terminated, [it gives the last status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/456974/190347), which is `50` as set earlier.
- In `sh` (as well as `ash`, [`ksh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42545488/3196753)) when you ask `wait` to wait for a process that's already terminated, it errors with `test.sh: line 9: wait: pid 27016 is not a child of this shell` which is `127`.

Comment: I intentionally wait for the same process twice. The `sleep` command is there just to make the exit code change to 127 on `ash`. You can replace it with `cat` or anything to achieve the same effect. Also, I think you are not correct when you claim that `wait` on `ash` will fail if the child process already terminated. I have been waiting for terminated process just fine (you can try putting a `sleep 4` line after the `sleep 3&` -- I just don't understand why the second call to `wait` returns 127.

Comment: Hi, the example provided uses `bash` and `sh`.  My claim about the process being gone is related to behavior with `sh`.  The message about the process missing wasn't present on Ubuntu using `sh` or `ash`, but it did show when testing MacOS, which is where the above conclusion was drawn.  The error is directly from the MacOS terminal, but is also available as an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42545488/3196753 (`ksh`, but same behavior).  That's identical behavior with 3 other shells, so `bash` really seems to be the outlier here.

Comment: Another useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71884901/3196753.  I'm sharing this because I'm not sure if your intention in the original example was to send `sleep` to the background or not (as it stands, I believe it sends `exit` to the background).  Regardless, in my tests `bash` sends the last background exit code whereas the other shells do not.

Comment: After some digging, I finally found someone else describing this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/456974/190347.  Added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

bash behaves the same way as busybox sh/dash in POSIX mode,

```
$ set -o posix
$ sleep 3 && exit 42 &
[1] 8573
$ wait $!; echo $?
[1]+  Done(42)                sleep 3 && exit 42
42
$ wait $!; echo $?
bash: wait: pid 8573 is not a child of this shell
127
```

and this is mentioned in [the official bash POSIX mode description](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/POSIX) as follows:

> 59. Bash removes an exited background process's status from the list
>     of such statuses after the 'wait' builtin is used to obtain it.

And wrt

> In `ash`, all commands put between 2 calls to `wait "${!}"` make the exit code change to 127, with the exception of `echo` command.

this looks like a bug that is fixed in NetBSD sh and FreeBSD sh but not in busybox sh and dash.